# How do I add a custom script to ubiquity source code that will create a few new folders on desktop when the installer finishes?

Tags: system-installation, scripts, ubiquity

edit:
I need to do this manually by tampering with the ubiquity source code, not with the help of some tool like Ubuntu builder

I need to have a few new folders and files be automatically created once ubiquity installation is complete.

Where do I add a custom script that can do this in the ubiquity source code?

Any sort of help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/49679/15811 has all you need to know. #1 is needed in your case to setup a chrooted env. When you add your scripts and directories to /etc/skel/ on the ISO they will be added to every /home/$USER/